# WebApi controller without multiple classes

Tags: .net, controller, routes, asp.net-web-api2

From what I understand, the route map with the format

```
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

maps the url "/api/file/1" to the controller "FileController" and the GET method contained within that controller which accepts a string input called "id". Similarly, if I had the url "/api/meeting/1", it would map to the controller "MeetingController" and the GET method accepting a string input called "id".

Is it possible to have both of the above two, instead, map to the same controller?

IE, can I somehow set up a "DefaultController", which takes the URL "/api/file/1", and maps it to a method called "GetData(string id)"? And then within that method, can I somehow obtain the "file" part?

The reason I ask this is because the "FileController" and "MeetingController" described above would, in implementation, be identical. The only difference would be that the parameter passed to the function which I use to get my data, would change from "file" to "meeting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{data}/{id}",
      defaults: new {
                      id = RouteParameter.Optional, 
                      controller = "Generic",
                      action = "GenericAction" 
                   }
);
```

Your controller:

```
public class GenericController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string GenericAction(string data, int? id)
    {
        return data + "-" + id.ToString();
    }
}
```

This
   http://localhost:53221/api/files/1 will return (if you accept xml)

```
string>files-1</string>
```

That said,I don't think what you are trying to do  makes sense.
If your controllers are similar use a base class

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks! But what do you mean by "use a base class"?

Comment: @KiranRamaswamy Use a base class for your controllers so you can reuse as much code as possible